# c++ why doesn't a copy of an object allow access to a private variable of the original?

Tags: c++, object

For example,

```
Number operator+(Number a, Number b) {

    return Number(a.x + b.x);


}
```

Would this cause some kind of "unable to access private member error". I understand that if I don't pass by reference, the Number a, and Number b are copied on the stack and used in the body of the function. However, I don't see why they do not allow access to the originals' private members. How am I misunderstanding the concept of an object? Also how come friend and member function don't need to pass by reference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`operator+` is an unbound function, i.e. it is not a member of `Number` so, this is the rule, it has no implicit access to private members.

The rule is not affected by you passing `Number` objects by value or by reference. Access protection is applied to *every* access to a `Number` object, even if  it is your private, stack-based copy.

There are at least three ways out:

- declare `Number operator+(Number, Number)` a friend of `Number`
- add a public getter for `x` so the variable is accessible.
- implement the `+=` operator as a member of the class and implement the free operator in terms of it: `return Number(a) += b;`

Answer (score 3):

You're definitely misunderstanding something. 'Pass by reference', 'copied on stack' etc. have absolutely nothing to do with the access rules.

The code above is an error because operator+ is not a member of Number, and (presumably) it's not a friend of Number either. So it cannot access private members. That's all there is to it.

Comment: So a copy of an object is allowed to access private members as long as it's used within a member function?

Comment: Copy has nothing to do with it. Think about code. There are two types of code in your program, the code that is allowed to access private members of Number and the code that isn't. Whether the object have been copied or not, whether they are on the stack or not, whether they are access by reference or not. None of these things have anything to do with it.

Comment: The short answer is yes, member functions can access private members of that class whenever and wherever they please.

Answer (score 0):

As many have answered operator + is not a member of Number class, it is a global variable. Consider a function `Show`:

```
void Show(const Number& numberObj) // const, by-ref is IMMATERIAL 
{
   std::cout<< numberObj.x;
}
```

and a method Show:

```
class Number
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    void Show()
    {
       std::cout << x;
    }
};
```

Now, if you replace `Show` with any overloaded operator, taking 1 or 2 arguments - only the class-member can access the private data, and global implementation cannot.

For this, you need to make global `Show` a **friend** of class (in class declaration), and likewise any globally implemented operator.